# Make full-control for me and disable deleting for everyone else on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

So I have a folder which I want to make shared over my LAN. I want everyone to read folder and files (maybe add/create new files), but I want prevent them from deleting. I used advanced security and this is "Allow permissions" for everyone:

[image]

Then here is "Full-control permission" for just me:

[image]

And the last one is "Deny for everyone":

[image]

But I'm still able to do things like everyone. I can't delete any file and so on, like my permissions are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deny permissions take a higher preference over allow permissions.

Given that you set deny permissions to the Everyone user, they also apply to you.

So in essence, you have counteracted your own rights by using deny rights.

From an administrator point of view, you almost never want to use deny permissions, unless you know exactly what you're doing. Not setting rights is also deny rights.

The order of rights are as follows, from top to bottom. If the criteria is met, that right is set.

Deny something
Allow something
Deny whatever was not set.

So if you set Deny for user X and also allow for user X, the first deny is used.

If you neither set deny for user Y nor Allow for user Y, then Deny whatever was not set is applied to user Y.

Also, lastly: The Everyone user, literally means everyone. Aka: this always has effect. Similarly, Full Control means: every right bit. So allowing all settings but Full Control, then denying Full Control, literally translates to: deny everything.